# Raspberry Pi Zero W, berryboot would not boot

Tags: pi-zero, pi-zero-w, boot-issues, kernel, berryboot

I am having difficulty installing berryboot on my pi zero. I followed countless guides and none seem to work. most guides tell me to download [berryboot from here](https://www.berryterminal.com/doku.php/berryboot) however the site does not have a download link for the zero anymore. The available download is for the Pi 3, 4, and Pi 400 not the zero. I have tried this version on my zero and the result was a rainbow screen and the ACT led started to [blink 7 times](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/led_blink_warnings.md) which means it is missing the kernel image. My SD card has "kernel_rpi64.img". From my understanding, the pi zero is a 32bit system and I'm assuming the kernel currently on my sd is not compatible. The problem is I don't know where I can find a compatible kernel image. I have located an [archive of berryboot versions](https://sourceforge.net/projects/berryboot/files/) and I have tried using older ones.

- berryboot-20201103-pi4.zip

  ```
  - missing kernel
  ```
- berryboot-20190612-pi0-pi1-pi2-pi3.zip

  ```
  - pi doesn't boot, no led lights
  ```
- I tried taking the kernel image from  berryboot-20190612-pi0-pi1-pi2-pi3.zip and use it in berryboot-20201103-pi4.zip

  ```
  - ACT led flashes two long flashes then rainbow screen displays
  ```

I have tested other versions and had no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not sure what the question is but their changelog dated 2019-06-12 shows *Single multiplatform kernel for ARMv6/ARMv7 supporting Pi0/Pi1/Pi2/Pi3* As for there being only NOC-PS - see issue 682 https://github.com/maxnet/berryboot/issues/682 Maybe look at PINN if you really want multiple OS support on one card.

Comment: the problem was I couldn't get berryboot working, il rename the question my bad. I have found that link but I couldn't make any use of it. thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

I just tried [berryboot-20181211-pi0-pi1-pi2-pi3.zip](https://cfhcable.dl.sourceforge.net/project/berryboot/berryboot-20181211-pi0-pi1-pi2-pi3.zip) and it seems to work fine except for its missing a few things. I can only install NOC-PS Lite from the internet and nothing else.